# Hash a vector of e.g. strings to obtain one-by-one sha256 vector of hashes (Python)

Tags: python, vector, hash, sha256

I wondered if there existed a Python function f which calculates the individual sha256 number of a vector at the same time. E.g. if you have a vector A=[a b], the function f gives f(A) = [sha256(a) sha256(b)] (a and b are strings or numbers).

I can't make it work with hashlib. In addition, the package 'openssl' from R has such function 'sha256'. Is there an equivalence?

I'm using Spyder IDE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [a,b]
Asha = list(map(sha256, A))
```

or

```
def sha256List(arr):
   return list(map(sha256, arr))

Asha = sha256List(A)
```

**Edit**

If you want a list with the `hexdigest` values you can use

```
def sha256HexDigestList(arr):
   return list(map(lambda x: sha256(x).hexdigest(), arr))

Asha_digest = sha256HexDigestList(A)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!
Can you also get a way to print the full list of hashes? The command "print(Asha[1].hexdigest())" prints the number at coordinate 1, but is there any more systematic way to print all the hashes?

Comment: @user27636 see edit, you can use the list of digest strings any way you want, maybe use `'  '.join(sha256HexDigestList(A))`

Comment: Yea, it works pretty well, thank you very, very much! Just note that the input is necessary an array of strings (if 1 string then array of 1 element).

Comment: Hello,
After some studies, it does not look like to be a proper "vectorization", since the time spent to calculate hashes this is overall equal to the one with one-by-one calculation (involving a loop).

Comment: @user27636 where in the question is the word vectorization and Python is single threaded because of the GIL